# stuff function is working with self join but not with right join in sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I found something very strange...stufff function working with self join but not working with left or right join,.
I have a table

**Id name**

1 samar

1 Harry

2 jack

I want the output as

**Id name**

1 samar Harry

2 jack

The below query works fine with self join

```
Select b.id, stuff ((select ` ` + a.name from #test a where a.id = b.id 
for xml path (``)),1,1,``)

From #test b

Group by id
```

But when i do right join i get error _ invalid object name `b`. Please let me know where i am going wrong....

```
Select b.id, stuff ((select ` ` + a.name from #test a 
right join b on b.id = a.id for xml path (``),1,1,``)

From #test b

Group by id
```

Comment: I think we can't use only aliases while using join (In your right join you are only mentioning the table alias b).

Comment: `b` is being treated as valid database object i.e. tablename or table valued function in this case rather than alias which is why it's throwing an error. If you want to join, you have to use tablename i.e. #test instead of b